# need to show only the duplicate value in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have table as

```
id----name----roll-----class
 1----ram-------1-----2
 2----shyam-----2-----3   
 3----ram-------1-----3
 4----shyam-----2-----3
 5----ram-------1-----2
 6----hari------1-----5
```

i need to find the the duplicate row only that have common **name, roll, class**. so the expected result for me is.

```
    id----name----roll-----class
     1----ram-------1-------2
     2----shyam-----2-------3           
     4----shyam-----2-------3
     5----ram-------1-------2
```

i tried to get from the query below but here only one field is supported. i need all three field common. Please do help me in this. thanks

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE tablefield IN ( 
 SELECT tablefield
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY tablefield  
 HAVING (COUNT(tablefield ) > 1) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) [over()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

```
select id, name, roll, class
from (select id, name, roll, class,
             count(*) over(partition by name, roll, class) as c
      from YourTable) as T
where c > 1
order by id
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63720/duplicates

Comment: thanks for your answer. i appreciate your example with upvote.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I doubt it, the chosen answer is gibberish

Comment: @ mickael well that didn't work but like he told if i put * in the count i think that will work. i have just randomly checked but i need to go thoroughly as my database is complex then i have given in example. i will let you know.

Comment: @Dinupkandel - Changing to `count(*)` will surface the next error in the query. You can not have `id` in the field list if it is not part of the group by clause.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson in my question i am looking for all column should perfectly match except id. what should i have have to do in OR condition i.e is if the data are common either in name or roll or class.

Answer (score 0):

this will retun only the duplicate entry one time:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.roll, t.class 
from table t 
inner join table t1 
on t.id<t1.id 
and t.name=t1.name 
and t.roll = t1.roll 
and t.class=t1.class
```

this will return what you require:

```
select distinct t.id, t.name, t.roll, t.class 
    from table t 
    inner join table t1 
    on t.name=t1.name 
    and t.roll = t1.roll 
    and t.class=t1.class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this

```
SELECT A.* FROM
Table A LEFT OUTER JOIN Table B
ON A.Id <> B.Id AND A.Name = B.Name AND A.Roll = B.Roll AND A.Class = B.Class
WHERE B.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i have a single table what does table A and B means. i didn't get it.

Comment: "FROM Table A" = "from table named "Table" which I'll refer to as "A" from now on in the query"

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work (I did not test though):

```
select a1.* 
from table a1, a2 
where (a1.id != a2.id) 
  and (a1.name == a2.name) 
  and (a1.roll== a2.roll)   
  and (a1.class== a2.class);
```

It seems there are several proprosals here. If it is a query that you'll use in your code, beware of the cost of the queries. Try an 'explain' with your database.